# converting specific technique from mysql to mysqli (php)

Tags: php, mysqli

In mysql I use this code

```
$somenumber=5;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table")
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['id'.$somenumber];
}
```

Please help me to do the same in the best way using mysqli, probably oop style I think cause everybody say best way to use oop way. Sorry I'm just studding this

Comment: i can give you a tip: use a framework (like CakePHP) and you dont have to worry about stuff like that. it will be done for you behind the DBO wrapper classes. you can then concentrate on more urgent matters.

Comment: sorry but I think better to learn everything yourself instead of starting to learn how that framework works not knowing ABC of programming  :)

Comment: There are OO examples on the PHP web site: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: "everybody say best way to use oop" is not a good reason to switch. Sprinkling 'oop' on an app doesn't make it magically better. OOP is one method of getting a programming job done, but it's the ONLY way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it with MySQLi OOP, you create an object, then call it's `query()` method.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('hostname','user','password','databasename');
if (!$mysqli) {
  // connect failure, check connect_error()
  echo $mysqli->connect_error();
}
else {
  // Call query() to execute your SQL
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM some_table");
  if ($result) {
    // $result is an object of type mysqli_result
    // Call fetch_assoc() on $result
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      echo $row['id'];
  }
}
```

If you have input parameters which you'll pass into your query, escape them with `real_escape_string()`

```
$somevar = $mysqli->real_escape_string($somevar);
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somecolumn='$somevar';");
```

The principle benefits of `MySQLi` over the older `mysql_*` API are

- The ability to use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of dynamic SQL strings
- Object-oriented behavior which can be `extend`ed with your own classes.

Comment: Is it possible to write $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM some_table") or die mysql_connect_error(); ???

Comment: by the way looks like the same mysql. Thinking why this is better then normal mysql.....

Comment: @David `$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM some_table") or die($mysqli->error);`  But using `die()` is a poor practice since it abruptly exits the whole script. Instead `if (!$result) //do some error handling`.

Comment: @David MySQLi's strength over regular `mysql_*` is that you can use prepared statements. See edit above.

Comment: @David re `fetch_object()` yes, I think could do it that way. You'd need to test yourself.

Comment: $row->id.$somenumber not working. Will open new question maybe someone has  any idea

Comment: @David try `$row->{"id".$somenumber}` I can't remember if that is valid